# ¿como extraer una dirección ip que está en un input a inputs diferentes?

Tags: javascript

Ejemplo, tengo lo siguiente:

```
192.168.1.2
```

Quiero extraer cada octeto de la IP de un input diferente.

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
<script>

                    function extraer_ip(){
                  if($("#action").val() == "edit" ){
                    //capturar la ip completa en editar y extraer valor por separado    
                     var ip_equipo = $("#ip_equipo").val();
                     var ip = ip_equipo.split(".");
             
                      $("#ip_1").val(ip[0]);  
                      $("#ip_2").val(ip[1]);  
                      $("#ip_3").val(ip[2]);  
                      $("#ip_4").val(ip[3]);  
                  }
                }
                extraer_ip();
</script>
```

Comment: Intenta con [split('.')](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split) y, por favor, edita la pregunta para agregar el código que no te funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tambien puedes hacerlo con jquery de la siguiente forma:

```js
var ip = '192.168.1.2';
var div = ip.split('.');
var output = ""
for (var element of div) {
  output += '<input type="text" value="' + element + '"><br>';
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#output').append(output);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>IP Address:</p>
<div id="output"></div>
```

De esta forma, si tienes un ip con un dato menos o mas por alguna razon, creara un input dinamicamente ya que los inputs se van agregando dependiendo de los valores separados por el punto.

Answer (score 2):

Podemos proceder de esta forma:

- Hacer uso de `split` para descomponer el *string* donde se almacena la IP por el símbolo que aparece en común que es el **.**
- A los inputs donde quieres asignar cada octeto de la IP le damos una clase en común
- Recuperamos en 2 variables a:

  - la dirección IP
  - Los 4 inputs por medio del método `querySelectorAll()`
- Por medio de un ciclo for iteramos desde 0 hasta una iteración cuyo valor sea menor a la lontitud de los 4 inputs recuperados previamente en la variable `segmentos`
- Por dentro del ciclo for para asignar valores a los inputs indicamos con esta sintaxis: `segmentos[inicio].value`
- Ahora para asignar el valor al atributo value y tomar cada octeto de forma dinámica lo indicamos por medio de: `IP_ADDRESS[inicio]`

  - De esta manera nos evitamos el paso que estás haciendo en tu código que es indicar de forma manual el índice dentro del vector que ocupa cada elemento con esto: `$("#ip_1").val(ip[0]);`

Código:

```html
      <div class="octetos">
        <input type="text" class="octeto">
        <input type="text" class="octeto">
        <input type="text" class="octeto">
        <input type="text" class="octeto">
      </div>
    <script>
        const IP_ADDRESS = '192.168.1.2'.split('.');
        const segmentos  = document.querySelectorAll('.octeto');

        for(let inicio = 0; inicio<segmentos.length; inicio++) {
          segmentos[inicio].value = IP_ADDRESS[inicio];
        }    
    </script>
```